# Parsing expressions with an undefined number of arguments

Tags: algorithm, parsing, nlp, rpn

I'm trying to parse a string in a self-made language into a sort of tree, e.g.:

```
# a * b1 b2 -> c * d1 d2 -> e # f1 f2 * g
```

should result in:

```
# a
  * b1 b2
    -> c
  * d1 d2
    -> e
# f1 f2
  * g
```

#, * and -> are symbols. a, b1, etc. are texts.

Since the moment I know only rpn method to evaluate expressions, and my current solution is as follows. If I allow only a single text token after each symbol I can easily convert expression first into RPN notation (b = b1 b2; d = d1 d2; f = f1 f2) and parse it from here:

a b c -> * d e -> * # f g * #

However, merging text tokens and whatever else comes seems to be problematic. My idea was to create marker tokens (M), so RPN looks like:

a M b2 b1 M c -> * M d2 d1 M e -> * # f2 f1 M g * #

which is also parseable and seems to solve the problem.

That said:

1. Does anyone have experience with something like that and can say it is or it is not a viable solution for the future?
2. Are there better methods for parsing expressions with undefined arity of operators?
3. Can you point me at some good resources?

Note. Yes, I know this example very much resembles Lisp prefix notation and maybe the way to go would be to add some brackets, but I don't have any experience here. However, the source text must not contain any artificial brackets and also I'm not sure what to do about potential infix mixins like # a * b -> [if value1 =  value2] c -> d.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: It seems that what I'm looking for are sources on postfix notation with a variable number of arguments.

Comment: Please have a look at your example, I think something is missing - f1, f2 and g seem to appear from nowhere.

Comment: You're right. I've added them later, when I wrote rest of the text. It is corrected now.

Comment: You should rephrase your question I can't really figure out wether you are trying to parse a prefix or a postfix notation

Comment: What I have is what is at the top - prefix notation. 

I find it however easier to first convert notation to postfix and then parse the postfix notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I couldn't fully understand your question, but it seems what you want is a grammar definition and a parser generator. I suggest you take a look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), it should be pretty straightforward with it to define a grammar for either your original syntax or the RPN.</s>

**Edit:** (After exercising self-criticism, and making some effort to understand the question details.) Actually, the language grammar is unclear from your example. However, it seems to me, that the advantages of the prefix/postfix notations (i.e. that you need neither parentheses nor a precedence-aware parser) stem from the fact that you *know the number of arguments* every time you encounter an operator, therefore you know exactly how many elements to read (for prefix notation) or to pop from the stack (for postfix notation). OTOH, I beleive that having operators which can have variable number of arguments makes prefix/postfix notations not simply difficult to parse but outright ambiguous.  Take the following expression for example:

```
# a * b c d
```

Which of the following three is the canonical form?

1. ## (a, *(b, c, d))
2. ## (a, *(b, c), d)
3. ## (a, *(b), c, d)

Without knowing more about the operators, it is impossible to tell. Of course you could define some sort of greedyness of the operators, e.g. * is greedier than #, so it gobbles up all the arguments. But this would beat the purpose of a prefix notation, because you simply wouldn't be able to write down the second variant from the above three; not without additinonal syntactic elements.

Now that I think of it, it is probably not by sheer chance that none of the programming languages I know support *operators* with a variable number of arguments, only *functions/procedures*.

Comment: Dear David, thanks for your time and for ANTLR link. What I'm actually doing is not a programming language and probably I've misled you by using term "operator". Real purpose of the language is a human-friendly serialization of a tree. 

Canonical form is 1 but I may introduce "end" lexems like /*

Comment: ctd.: So # a * b c /* d will result in #(a *(b, c), d).

I am also happy to report that approach using articial marker lexems seems to be working so far.

Comment: #a * b c /* d would than be rpn'ed into:

M a M c b * d #

Comment: And also the whole thing starts to resemble TeX